C++ Data Structure to do this?
I have a class called logic which holds a single criteria to evaluate. A different object can have up to 20 of these criteria. I currently have an array containing multiple of these Logic classes. I can loop through the array and call evaluate on all of the Logic classes, then AND all of the results together to get a final result, which has been working. However, I am now needing to not only AND the results, but also OR. Is there a data structure to define something like (LOGIC1 && LOGIC2) || LOGIC3 that could link how these classes relate better than an array? The only criteria is that it has to be easy to ready when defining the structure, so something like this:
LOGIC(HEIGHT, GREATER_THAN, 50),
AND,
LOGIC(HEIGHT, LESS_THAN, 100),
OR,
LOGIC(WEIGHT, LESS_THAN, 500)
Here is a simple version of the code.
enum class OPERATION
{
    GREATER_THAN,
    LESS_THAN
};
enum class CONDITION
{
    HEIGHT,
    WEIGHT
};

class Logic
{
    CONDITION con;
    OPERATION op;
    double op2;

    public:
    bool evaulate(CONDITION con, double op1){
        if(con == CONDITION::HEIGHT)
            {
            if(op == OPERATION::GREATER_THAN)
            {
                return op1 > op2;
            }
            else if(op == OPERATION::LESS_THAN)
            {
                return op1 < op2;
            }
        }
    }
    Logic(CONDITION a, OPERATION b, double c){
        con = a;
        op = b;
        op2 = c;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::array<Logic, 2> statements = {
        Logic(CONDITION::HEIGHT, OPERATION::GREATER_THAN, 7.31),
        Logic(CONDITION::WEIGHT, OPERATION::LESS_THAN, 100.0)
        //would also want like OR Logic(CONDITION::WEIGHT, OPERATION::LESS_THAN, 100.0)
    };

    //loop through the statements and evauluate
}


Did you ran by title of book "Design patterns" by so-called band of four? There was something similar.. It's not one pattern, but several, a Builder is main part, I think.

@Swift-FridayPie band of four -> gang of four

@user4581301 Stupid SwiftKey replaces it with band if these words are together. Is that some movie?

@Swift-FridayPie This? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gang_of_Four

Nah. Band of four was a British post-punk band. I hoped you'd get the correction in time for an edit.

If you have multiple "rules" like "(A1 and B1) or C1" ...etc. Then you might want to have an expression tree for it. Evaluate each "boolean"(A1..n, B1...n, C1...n)  and then confirm if any "rule" is matched. There is no simple data structure to achieve it but you may try to use "policy engine" as a keyword to search for libraries.

You have a couple of obvious choices. One would be a tree, so (for example) (foo or bar) and baz would be represented something like this:

Then at each node, you have either a value, or an operator. Each operator gets applied to its children, and produces a value for that node, which is then used as the operand by the parent.
The other obvious possibility would be an array. This is basically a flattened version of the tree, usually in RPN1 form, so for the same expression you'd get something like this:

Then you walk through the array, and evaluate it as RPN, using a stack. So when the item in the array is an operand, you load the operand to the top of the stack. When you get to an operator, you grab the top items from the stack, apply the operator, and load the result back onto the stack.
At the end of this, you should have one value at the top of the stack, which represents the final value of the expression.


RPN stands for Reverse Polish Notation, sort of the reverse of Polish Notation, which was invented by Jan Łukasiewicz.


RPN = Reverse Policy Notation since this wasn't mentioned in the answer.

@LouisGo: Ooops--I've edited, with the full name.
